# C# data reader does not retrieve the data

Tags: c#

I am trying to load data into a textbox by using a `DataReader` depend on the Drop down list selection. Didn't get error from this code, but the data is not loaded into textbox. please correct me.

```
public void text()
{
    cn1.Open();
    string s;
    s = "select Request_Type from component where Material_Code='" + Mcodeddl.SelectedItem.Text + "' ";

    SqlCommand cd1 = new SqlCommand(s, cn1);
    SqlDataReader rd;

    try
    {
        rd = cd1.ExecuteReader();

        while (rd.Read())
        {
            TextBox4.Text = rd["Request_Type"].ToString().Trim();
        }

        rd.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cd1.Dispose();
        cn1.Close();
    }
}

public void MC()
{
    Mcodeddl.Items.Clear();
    ListItem li1 = new ListItem();
    li1.Text = "-Select-";
    Mcodeddl.Items.Add(li1);
    Mcodeddl.SelectedIndex = 0;

    cn1.Open();
    string s1;
    s1 = "select Material_Code from component";

    SqlCommand cd1 = new SqlCommand(s1, cn1);
    SqlDataReader dr1;

    try
    {
        dr1 = cd1.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            ListItem ni1 = new ListItem();
            ni1.Text = dr1["Material_Code"].ToString().Trim();
            Mcodeddl.Items.Add(ni1);
        }

        dr1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cd1.Dispose();
        cn1.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: the two methods were called by radio button selection

Comment: Advice: In the debugger get the value of the variable s before the query is run and then run it directly in the database to see if you get what you expect.

Comment: Also, please describe in your question (with an edit) the behavior you expect and the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: SQL Injection alert: your data access code is dangerously unsafe; unrelated to the question, but please lookup SQL injection and parameters.

Comment: You need to help debug this... if you play it in the IDE, does it enter the `while` body? how many times? does it jump to the `catch`? We aren't psychic...

Comment: Is your reader returning rows? You can check this with dr1.HasRows property. Debug your code. Check this MSDN link on DataReader which has some best practices to follow. `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.100).aspx`

Answer (score 0):

If everything works fine without exceptions that is mean the connection established correctly and the SQL command is correct. I think you have to make sure about your SQL statement. Maybe it returns nothing because there are no matches.

We need more explain about your issue.